# Connecting Firebase Authentication with Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm struggling with connecting Firebase Authentication with Firebase Database on my iOS app.

The users are successfully authenticated and appear in Authentication section in Firebase but the data (e.g. names / emails) doesn't show in Firebase Database where it should be stored. I've pasted the code and the warnings of debug area below.

Code:

```
 @objc func handleRegister() {

    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text
        else {
            print("form is not valid")
            return
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (res, err) in

        if let err = err {
            print(err)
            return
        }


        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        self.ref.child("users").child(userId!).setValue(["username": name, "email": email]) {
            (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Data could not be saved: \(error).")
            } else {
                print("Data saved successfully!")
            }
        }

    })
}
```

> Warnings of debug area:
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:06.735883+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241459]
>   libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not
>   supported on this platform.
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:06.874146+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241580] 5.16.0
>   - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available. To add it, include Firebase/Core in the Podfile or add
>   FirebaseAnalytics.framework to the Link Build Phase
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:08.015632+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241459]
>   [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:09.123610+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241459] [MC]
>   System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   path is
>   /Users/mikolajsemeniuk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20AB5C8F-2A8E-4F49-8DA6-0BB11A11958F/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:09.125330+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241459] [MC]
>   Reading from private effective user settings.
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:19.325723+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241579]
>   [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID:
>   -234567.MyAwesomeProject due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled 2019-02-06 19:29:23.627072+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5242009]
>   [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301)
>   [C1.1:2][0x7fa94a80b030] get output frames failed, state 8196
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.627344+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5242009]
>   [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301)
>   [C1.1:2][0x7fa94a80b030] get output frames failed, state 8196
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.628087+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5242009] TIC
>   Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.628233+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5242009] TIC
>   Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.950084+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241765]
>   [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301)
>   [C2.1:2][0x7fa948614e70] get output frames failed, state 8196
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.950399+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241765]
>   [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301)
>   [C2.1:2][0x7fa948614e70] get output frames failed, state 8196
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.951137+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241765] TIC
>   Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
>
> 2019-02-06 19:29:23.951409+0100 MyAwesomeProject[72154:5241765] TIC
>   Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57 (lldb)

Comment: Just use `Database.database().reference()`, Do not init it with URL. [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write?authuser=0)

Comment: Where is the log of `Data could not be saved because of\(error)` or `Data saved sucesfully`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your property list file `plist` decides about what Firebase Project to use, so no need to specify this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL:"https://myawesomeproject29133.firebaseio.com/")
```

Instead, you make a global variable called `ref` above the `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

In your `handleUser()`:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
let userid =  Auth.auth().currentUser.uid
self.ref.child("users").child(userid).setValue(["name": name,"email": email])
```

> Also, I highly recommend you to continue without saving someones password, Unless you encrypt them. You shouldn't store them nakedly. It's stored in Google's servers and you have absolutely zero reasons to view someone else's password.

Comment: First of all 

thanks for anwersing and also for advises like not storing the passwords and also about making global variable

but there is a one more problem, exactly I put the code you told me in my handleUser()  but the Xcode showed me to unwrap this one, I did it by using ? and also guard let but still shows me that found nil while unwrapping and I couldn't figure it out using ? and guard or even !

Could you also recomend how to safely unwrap this, because i guess that the problem is with userid.

And once more thanks for help, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Give me a few hours when I get to my desk I’ll be happy to assist you

Comment: ok, no problem and thanks again and also sry for trouble but I nearly started with Firebase.

Comment: yeah, sure, just give my 5 min pls

Comment: I updated the comment above, now there is a actual code, but now the problem is that every time i try to press the registerbutton it shows me, that "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and still could't unwrap this safely using guard let or if let

Comment: That's because no user is signed in as of that moment, this line is nill `let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` there's no unwrapping way around this, you can't provide a default value otherwise the data won't go to the appropriate place. Do you have authentication enabled in your firebase settings?

Comment: Also in which line, specifically does it show that error?

Comment: this error shows exactly in line         self.ref.child("users").child(userId!).setValue(["username": name, "email": email]) {

Comment: I've got email and password authentication enabled in my firebase settings

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, thanks everybody for help, now my program works correctly